# Error message in CatcheNetworkImage not showing after i turn off my network

Tags: flutter

The error message in the catched network image is not displaying after i turn off my network.
It keep showing the images even when the network is off.

The error message is not showing on the app to the users.

Here is the code

```
class ProductList extends StatefulWidget {
  final ProductModel productInfo;

  const ProductList({
    super.key,
    required this.productInfo,
  });

  @override
  State<ProductList> createState() => _ProductListState();
}

class _ProductListState extends State<ProductList> {


  bool isChanged = false;

  void toggleIcon() {
    setState(() {
      isChanged = !isChanged;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        var productService =
            Provider.of<ProductService>(context, listen: false);
        productService.onProductSelected(widget.productInfo);
      },
      child: Card(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Hero(
                  tag: widget.productInfo.imgUrl_1!,
                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                    height: 180,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    imageUrl: widget.productInfo.imgUrl_1!,
                    placeholder: (context, url) => SizedBox(
                      child: Center(
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: 30,
                          width: 30,
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            color: AppColors.kPrimaryColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                        const Icon(Icons.error),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The error message in the catched network image is not displaying after i turn off my network.
It keep showing the images even when the network is off.

The error message is not showing on the app to the users.